# How to single step into runtime code in Golang

Tags: go, debugging, assembly, runtime

I wonder how can I single step into runtime code (presumably in Visual Studio Code). I don't think this problem ties to any specific version of Go, but for context, I'm using 1.18.3 on Intel Mac.

What I want to do: given the source code, I want to track how map assignment happens thru the call chain.

```
package main

func main() {
    m := make(map[int]int)
    m[1] = 100
}
```

Current approach: I'm using Delve (version 1.9.0) and set a breakpoint on line 5 `m[1] = 100` statement. Then I can use [step-instruction](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/README.md#step-instruction) to navigate thru the assembly-level code like

```
        map-example.go:4        0x105a979       8401                    test byte ptr [rcx], al
        map-example.go:4        0x105a97b       89410c                  mov dword ptr [rcx+0xc], eax
        map-example.go:4        0x105a97e       488d9c24c8000000        lea rbx, ptr [rsp+0xc8]
        map-example.go:4        0x105a986       48899c24a8000000        mov qword ptr [rsp+0xa8], rbx
        map-example.go:5        0x105a98e       488d05ab580000          lea rax, ptr [rip+0x58ab]
=>      map-example.go:5        0x105a995       b901000000              mov ecx, 0x1
        map-example.go:5        0x105a99a       e86142fbff              call $runtime.mapassign_fast64
        map-example.go:5        0x105a99f       48898424b0000000        mov qword ptr [rsp+0xb0], rax
        map-example.go:5        0x105a9a7       8400                    test byte ptr [rax], al
        map-example.go:5        0x105a9a9       48c70064000000          mov qword ptr [rax], 0x64
        map-example.go:6        0x105a9b0       488bac24f8000000        mov rbp, qword ptr [rsp+0xf8]
```

I've tried [step](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/README.md#step) function but I think it skips the built-in function and jumps to the next line at the source code level directly.

Question: is there any other way to debug/track the runtime code other than assembly level. Particularly I want to track `runtime.mapassign_fast64` or `runtime.mapaccess1`.

Thanks for your time and I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can use `stepi` to single step instruction by instruction.  Once you are in the internal function, you can then single step line by line again.

Comment: @fuz thanks for replying. I'm doing that right now, but I think internal function is presented at the assembly level. I wonder whether there is a way to step into the Go-code level.

Comment: Did you try using the delve debugger available in VS Code? You can read this doc for setup steps, supported features, configurations, information on remote debugging and a troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging